# MySQL transport protocol integrity check

Tags: mysql, ssh

I am interested whether low level transport protocol of MySQL has some checksums or other integrity check? If I use SSH tunnel with interruptions, is it safe that commands will be received intact and MySQL server will ignore broken data (return error)? I guess SSH encryption will help to protect from random concatenation of partial commands (e.g. DELETE FROM with arguments from next commands and lost data in between).

Comment: MySQL protocol uses TCP, which itself has checksums to detect errors.

Comment: @BillKarwin Maybe this is wrong: https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=15774966 "Lost packets between SSH client and SSH server do not cause retransmits on either application side."

Comment: "with interruptions" needs to be further clarified. A tunnelled packet in a TCP SSH connection is still just a TCP packet. If in doubt, set up a test environment.

Comment: @danblack Interruptions means that device is connected via GPRS, network coverage is not 100% guaranteed and signal may be bad. SSH tunnel will be recovered but if data is lost in the middle of request packet, I want to know whether MySQL protocol will detect it with its own checksum. I think it is normal to have it.

Comment: sounds like ssh is just relaying on tcp resends. Or maybe its a window. Not sure how helpful ssh is with forwards ports. There are sequence numbers in MySQL packets to detect losses.